# CSS - width vs. height - width has priority

Tags: html, css

I encountered quite a specific problem that doesn't seem to be addressed anywhere. When I have both fixed width and height on a containing div, then any text inside the div only overflows vertically, but not horizontally.

> Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TgPRM/1382/

```
#container {
   height:50px;
   max-height:50px;
   width:50px;
}
```

Now what is even stranger width has priority even if I wrap the text inside a paragraph and set a fixed height/max-height (but not width!) on that paragraph. The text chooses to disrespect the height set on its parent element, and instead respect the width set on its grand-parent element.

> Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TgPRM/1377/

My question is, why is given width **so much priority** and what can we do for the text to overflow horizontally rather than vertically?

Edit: I want to keep *overflow:visible* so any solution based on *overflow* property does not address my problem. *White-space:nowrap* seems a bit extreme solution, as it doesn't even respect browser window dimensions (try a very very long text). Thus, I accepted Evan's solution as it works exactly as I expected already my example to work.

Comment: Replace this to your #container{ height:auto; max-height:auto;}

Comment: Do you want:
(1) the container to stretch so that the text fits 
(2) hide text that is outside of the container
(3) the user to be able to scroll to get to all of the text?

Comment: you want the text to overflow horizontally even with a fixed widith?

Comment: How wide are you trying to make it overflow horizontally?  Without a width specified, how is the container suppose to know how wide to be?  Do you want all the text on one line?  You can do `white-space: nowrap;` if so.  Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish??

Comment: The text doesn't disrespect the height of any of the elements. Neither of the elements is growing in height. This is true even if you remove the max-height declaration. Nothing is taking priority here.

Comment: You can prove BoltClock's statement by adding `overflow: hidden`. Once the area is filled, the text is hidden.

Comment: Yes, you are right, @BoltClock and Katana314. Maybe I used wrong word, by disrespect I meant overflow. But my question was, why does it overflow only vertically, and not horizontally in the first place?

Comment: @SeanStopnik I would expect it to be as wide as possible. After all, isn't that how block elements are supposed to behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this suffice?

http://jsfiddle.net/TgPRM/1385/

```css
#wrapper{
    position:relative; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#container{
height:100px;
max-height:100px;
width:50px;
background-color:red;
}

p {
    background-color:green;
    height:50px;
    max-height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container"><p>hello this is a very long long long long paragraph</p></div></div>
```

Comment: Yes, now it behaves exactly as I would *expect* it to behave. That is: the text overflows first horizontally and only then (if it reaches the end of the site) vertically. But why does it only work with that position? Is it because `position:absolute` creates a new block-formatting context?

Comment: @smartly - no, it's because the containing block of the p element, because it is `position:absolute` is it's nearest positioned ancestor, which is the #wrapper div. You can see that if you set a width to that div, the p element's width will be restricted to the width given.

Comment: @Alohci Oh I see. Also, try put not only width, but also height to the wrapper div. Now we have the same peculiar behaviour as in my original example: the text overflows only vertically, but not horizontally.

Comment: @smartly check out my updated answer. You don't need `position: absolute`, you can use only `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not priority — it's simple word wrapping. You can check it if your word'll be very long (http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/y4wkmvcs/1/):

```
<div id="container">
    <p>hello_this_is_a_very_long_long_long_long_paragraph</p>
</div>
```

You can't fit any content in container with fixed `width` and `height`. If you want it, you shouldn't use fixed `width` and `height` — maybe use `min-width` or `min-height`.

If you want content overflows container only horizontally, you could do it this way (http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/5079bkdr/):

```
p {
    background-color:green;
    height:50px;
    max-height:50px;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

It all depends on your specific problem.

Comment: @smartly check out my updated answer. You don't need `position: absolute`, you can use only `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't specified how you want the browser to handle overflow for the `div` element so its up to the browser to pick for you. In order to get what I think you want you'll need something like this:

```
#container{
    height:50px;
    max-height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow-x: scroll;  /* Scrolls horizontally */
    overflow-y: hidden;  /* Doesn't scroll vertically */
    white-space: nowrap; /* Text doesn't automatically wrap due to width */
}
```